# Chrome Page Monitor regex

Tags: regex, google-chrome, monitoring

I'm using Chrome Page Monitor to monitor websites. It has two modes, Selection and Regex.
In selection mode, I get something like Regex code for example:

```
#topContent>div.sectionContent.gridlined7>div.sectionColumns>div.column1.gridPanel.grid7>div.module>div.moduleBody>div.topStory
```

I want to combine a regex it with the above code to match some words in this selection. For example I want to find the words "buy" and "acquisition" in this part. I wrote this Regex code:

```
\Wbuy\W|\Wacquisition\W
```

Could somebody explain how to combine these two regex fragments together?

Answer (score -1):

Factor out the prefix and suffix patterns

```
\W(buy|acquisition)\W
```

Comment: thanks alot, if i want to search the "acquisition" word in the title that the selector is point to..how can i implement it?

Comment: Thanks,But how I can combine it with the selection part. I just want to find these words in the selection part.